# Extending (mapped) tuple types

Tags: typescript, rxjs

When using tuple types in generic functions, how can you 'extend' the source type?

Let's say we want to make a RxJS mapping operator that returns the source observable value(s) together with another mapped value:

```js
export function mapExtended<T, R>(mapping: (input: [T]) => R): OperatorFunction<[T], [T, R]>;
export function mapExtended<T1, T2, R>(mapping: (input: [T1, T2]) => R): OperatorFunction<[T1, T2], [T1, T2, R]>;
export function mapExtended<T1, T2, T3, R>(mapping: (input: [T1, T2, T3]) => R): OperatorFunction<[T1, T2, T3], [T1, T2, T3, R]>;
export function mapExtended<R>(mapping: (input: any) => R): OperatorFunction<any, {}> {
    return (source$: Observable<any>) => source$.pipe(
        map(input => {
            const mappingResult = mapping(input);
            return [...input, mappingResult];
        }),
    );
}
```

That seems to work but the overloads aren't detected properly. The return type for `test` is, `Observable<[[number, number], number]>` instead of the expected `Observable<[number, number, number]>`:

```js
const test = combineLatest(of(1), of(2)).pipe(
    mapExtend(([s1, s2]) => s1 + s2),
);
```

Is there some sort of conditional type checking to say `T` cannot be a tuple type?

---

I tried accomplishing the same with mapped type support for tuples, but to no avail, as I cannot seem to (or I do not know how to) 'extend' the mapped type:

```js
type MapExtended2Input<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
function mapExtended2<T extends any[], R>(mapping: (input: MapExtended2Input<T>) => R): OperatorFunction<MapExtended2Input<T>, [MapExtended2Input<T>, R]> {
    return (source$: Observable<MapExtended2Input<T>>) => source$.pipe(
        map(input => {
            const mappingResult = mapping(input);
            const result: [MapExtended2Input<T>, R] = [input, mappingResult];
            return result;
        }),
    );
}

const test2 = combineLatest(of(1), of(2)).pipe(
    mapExtended2(([s1, s2]) => s1 + s2),
);
```

Here, the return type is also `Observable<[[number, number], number]>`, which is expected, but I do not know how to 'add' a type to the mapped tuple type. Intersecting doesn't seem to work or I'm doing it wrong.

An example of the desired functionality without RxJS would be:

Let's say I need a function `myFunc` thats has 2 generic type parameters:

- a tuple type T, with variable number of elements
- another type R

The result of the function should need to be a tuple type containing all elements of the tuple type T with the parameter of type R appended to it.

e.g.:

```js
myFunc<T, R>(x, y); // Should return [T, R]
myFunc<[T1, T2], R>(x, y); // Should return [T1, T2, R]
myFunc<[T1, T2, T3], R>; // Should return [T1, T2, T3, R]
// ...
```

Comment: What is rxjs, what do the `of` and `pipe` functions do? And if the question is about a specific library, why isn't it tagged/named appropriately?

Comment: @m93a: The usage of rxjs is irrelevant to the question, but I've added the tag to be complete, thanks. For your information, rxjs is quite a popular library: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Comment: The code is just too complex. Try to replace the unnecessary types like `OperatorFunction` and `Observable` with something different, so that we can replicate that in pure TypeScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is: given a tuple type `L` (for "list") and another type `T`, produce a new tuple type with `T` appended onto the end of `L`.  Sort of the resulting type if you were to call `l.push(t)`.  You can do that like this:

```
type Push<L extends any[], T> =
  ((r: any, ...x: L) => void) extends ((...x: infer L2) => void) ?
  { [K in keyof L2]-?: K extends keyof L ? L[K] : T } : never
```

This is a bit of trickery using [rest tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), [conditional type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types), and [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays)...

It's easy enough to produce the result of *prepending* a type onto the beginning of a tuple, since TypeScript introduced a type-level correspondence between function parameters and tuple types, and the ability to spread tuple types into rest parameters. If `L` is a tuple like `[string, number]`. then the function type `(...args: L)=>void` represents a function taking two parameters of types `string` and `number` respectively.  Rest parameters can have stuff before them: `(first: boolean, ...args: L)=>void` is a function taking three parameters.  And, the conditional type `((first: boolean, ...args: L) => void) extends ((...args: infer L2)=>void) ? L2 : never` produces a new tuple `L2` where `boolean` is *prepended* to the contents of `L`... such as `[boolean, string, number]`.

But you don't want prepending, you want *appending*. Well, by prepending any element to your list tuple `L`, we get a tuple `L2` of the right length but with the wrong types.  Ah, but we can map tuples!  Let's map over the numeric keys `K` of `L2`, using the conditional type `K extends keyof L ? L[K] : T`.  That is, if the numeric key `K` is in `L` (`"0"` or `"1"` if `L` is length `2`), then just use the corresponding type from `L`.  If not, it must be the one at the very end (`"2"` if `L` is length `2`), so use the new type `T` there.  This should have the effect of appending `T` to the end of `L`.

Let's make sure it works:

```
type P = Push<[1, 2, 3], 4>; // type P = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Looks good.  Now you can declare your `mapExtended()` like this:

```
declare function mapExtended<T extends any[], R>(
  mapping: (input: T) => R
): OperatorFunction<T, Push<T, R>>;
```

Note that the *implementation* of `mapExtended()` might not type check, because the compiler can't easily verify that something is of type `OperatorFunction<T, Push<T, R>>` for generic `T` and `R`.  So you will probably want to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

I can't verify the behavior of this because I don't have rxjs installed.  If you need rxjs-specific help I'm sure someone more knowledgeable about it will come along.  Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Nice! I tried using rest tuples but couldn't come up with the correct solution. Indeed, the implementation does not type check. When trying to figure it out, I also didn't think about on how to distinguish between a tuple type of multiple source Observables or a single Observable of an Array type. Although the intent of the desired operator function was clear, I might need to rethink the implementation because of the technical limitations. Nevertheless, your solution is what I was after and will certainly help with the final implementation, thanks!