# Push type to the end of the tuple

Tags: typescript, tuples

I can add element to the begining of the tuple, or remove it from there

```
type ShiftTuple<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => void) extends ((x: infer X, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
type UnshiftTuple<X, T extends any[]> = ((x: X, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

But I have difficulties with doing the same things with the last element instead of the first.

Even if I write the function

```
function f<X, Z extends any[]>(x: X, ...args: Z) {
  return [...args, x]
}
```

typescript [says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.1.6&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=43#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPADQDSIFqIKYAeUeYAJgM6ICGYAngNoC6AfABQEBcimiAdP1QBOAc3JdsASkQBvALAAoRIkF4oIQUnr9eQ0VgKMFAXwUKAbkMQFEAXmSsAjNUoOsAJmeI3WAMyefWAAsnoESANxAA) it returns `any[]`.

Is there a way to push new type into the end of the tuple like (insupported)

```
export type PushTuple<T extends any[], X> = [...T, X];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending (mapped) tuple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667014/extending-mapped-tuple-types)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE FOR TS4.0+

TypeScript 4.0 introduced [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), which supports `Push`ing to the end of a tuple in a much more straightforward way... like this:

```
type Push<T extends readonly any[], V> = [...T, V];
```

---

OLD ANSWER FOR TS3.9-:

I usually define `Push` in terms of what you're calling `Unshift` (but which I call [`Cons`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists)), like this:

```
type Cons<H, T extends readonly any[]> =
    ((head: H, ...tail: T) => void) extends ((...cons: infer R) => void) ? R : never;

type Push<T extends readonly any[], V>
    = T extends any ? Cons<void, T> extends infer U ?
    { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : V } : never : never;
```

The way `Push<T, V>` works is to make a tuple one element longer than `T` (which it does with `Cons`) and then it [maps over it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  It fills the initial elements of the output with the corresponding elements from `T`, and then anything left over it fills in `V`.  The only element index in a mapped tuple of length *n+1*  that is not an index of a tuple of length *n* is the index *n* itself, so that means the last element of the new tuple is `V`.  (I made sure to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) over `T` in case it's a union.)

Note that this only works for non-edge cases... don't expect [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples), [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types), and [rest](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) tuple elements or non-tuple arrays to behave well; you'd have to work around those restrictions yourself if you want to define it.

---

RESUME REGULAR ANSWER:

So then you can define `f()` like this:

```
function f<X, Z extends any[]>(x: X, ...args: Z): Push<Z, X>;
function f(x: any, ...args: any[]): any[] {
    return [...args, x]
}
```

(note that I use an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to free myself from worrying about the compiler trying and failing to understand that the implementation complies with `Push<Z, X>`:

And it works as you expect:

```
const s = f(4, "hey", false);
// const s: [string, boolean, number]
console.log(s); // ["hey", false, 4]
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBACgrgZwBYB4AqUIA9gQHYAmCUAThAIYED2eANiFOXiANoC6ANFAGoB8UAXigsAdGLRdubANwAoWQDM4eAMbAAljSgKUADS4AtTDnxFGzdrwAUWAFxR9UMSPIkA5gnsGAlPfjIUAy5dXjklVQ0tBRt7JhAuZ1cPWIs2X3NWNigAb1kofNIIYDgSPGFE9wQuLDZZAF95FRoEYChiIWiAFi4AIiQIEB6uBXJaBAhvOQB6KagmvBa2+xYWknU8Ny4AIyoqWgo8Ljw4AFstiBJa+YQ9iBFaKjcrBEmoGeE+gaHtUfGuTrYQA)

Comment: Why do you need `T extends any ?` check?

Comment: It's the "distribute over union" part... `Push<[1, 2] | [3], 4>` becomes `[1, 2, 4] | [3, 4]` with `T extends any`, as presumably expected.  Without it, you get `never` or something else weird.

Comment: Is it possible to ajust this solution to fit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58560747/4928642)?

Comment: The 4.0 solution should have `any[]` not `any`.