# Typescript - add one argument to a function's params

Tags: typescript

```
type SomeFunc = (a:string, b:number, c:someCustomType) => number;
```

I want to create a type that is just like the one above, except there is a single parameter added at the end. Let's say, `d:number`;

```
type SomeFuncAltered = (a:string, b:number, c:someCustomType, d:number) => number;
```

I do not want to craft the entire type manually though, I'm pretty sure there's a smart trick with `Parameters<func>` to be used here.

Comment: If it was being added at the front, you could do this: `type Alter<T extends (...args: any) => any> = (extraArg: number, ...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>;`. I don't know how to add it at the end though, since rest args can only be at the end.

Comment: Front is simple :) but end is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible but quite sophisticated. More info can be found in this answer from @jcalz - [Push type to the end of the tuple with skipping optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560747/push-type-to-the-end-of-the-tuple-with-skipping-optional) .

In your case we can reuse some utilities from above answer, exactly it would be `Cons` and `Push` and by using them make final type you need `AddArgument`. Consider:

```
type SomeFunc = (a: string, b: number, c: string) => number;

// some utility types for working with tuples
type Cons<H, T extends readonly any[]> =
    ((head: H, ...tail: T) => void) extends ((...cons: infer R) => void) ? R : never;

type Push<T extends readonly any[], V>
    = T extends any ? Cons<void, T> extends infer U ?
    { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : V } : never : never;

// final type you need
type AddArgument<F, Arg> = 
F extends ((...args: infer PrevArgs) => infer R) 
? (...args: Push<PrevArgs, Arg>) => R : never

// function type with added boolean argument at the end
type NewFunction = AddArgument<SomeFunc, boolean>
```

Comment: That is... epic.

Answer (score 17):

As the accepted answer here doesn't seem to work for me (using TS 4), I wrote my own type that adds any number of parameters to the end of a function.

```js
type AddParameters<
  TFunction extends (...args: any) => any,
  TParameters extends [...args: any]
> = (
  ...args: [...Parameters<TFunction>, ...TParameters]
) => ReturnType<TFunction>;
```

Usage:

```js
type SomeFunc = (a: string, b: number, c: someCustomType) => number;
type SomeFuncAltered = AddParameters<SomeFunc, [d: number]>;
// SomeFuncAltered = (a:string, b:number, c:someCustomType, d:number) => number;
```

**Note:** This solution also allows you to add named parameters.

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING, thank you! If anyone doesn't want to make a generic type for whatever reason you can just replace the arguments. For example, I'm extending the fetch API for a Keycloak OAuth fetch wrapper: 

`type FetchSecure = (
  ...args: [...[keycloak: KeycloakInstance], ...Parameters<typeof fetch>]
) => ReturnType<typeof fetch>;` 

Note Keycloak argument had to come first since the init? param of fetch is optional :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use additional type for the base function args:

```
type FuncBaseArgs = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

type SomeFunc = ({...obj }: FuncBaseArgs) => number;

type SomeFuncAltered = ({...obj }: FuncBaseArgs, d: number) => number;
```

Comment: Nice. Not Generic, but very practical.