# Typescript - adding an extra function parameter

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, variadic-tuple-types

I am trying to create a helper type which can convert a function of type

```
type Func1 = (id: string) => void;
```

to

```
type Func2 = (id: string, conf: { extraArg: boolean }) => void;
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324381/10597328) which does work, however it names the first argument as **head** and the following one would be named **id** if I were to apply my example which is very misleading.

I cranked up this code a bit for my purposes

```
type Cons<T extends readonly any[], H> =
        ((head: H, ...tail: T) => void) extends ((...cons: infer R) => void) ? R : never;

type Push<T extends readonly any[], V>
        = T extends any ? Cons<T, void> extends infer U ?
            { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : V } : never : never;

export type FunctionWithExtraArgument<F extends (...args: any[]) => any, Arg, R> = (...args: Push<Parameters<F>, Arg>) => R;
```

However I still couldn't get a complete solution which resolves the naming problem.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use code from above answer now. At the time of writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323726/typescript-add-one-argument-to-a-functions-params/60324381#60324381) there was not [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).

Now you can achieve it with help of only one util:

```js
type Func1 = (id: string) => void;


type Func2 = (id: string, conf: { extraArg: boolean }) => void;

type AddArgument<
  Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any,
  NextArg
  > =
  Fn extends (...arg: [...infer PrevArg]) => infer Return
  ? (...args: [...PrevArg, NextArg]) => Return
  : never;

// type Result = (args_0: string, args_1: {
//     extraArg: boolean;
// }) => void
type Result = AddArgument<Func1, { extraArg: boolean }>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYEYoF4oAoCWATALigGdgAnHBAcwEoMA%20KANwHt8BuAKG9ElkSQAmDNnxFSFagBooSFggBmRAN5QIAD3IBDAIJkqRAEYsWAGwhaEUAL510jVhx7hoOvHj1U4AWwgJgADycULBWGsB%20eMTYAHRxWvrERJYgANoAunaMKVLBUABy4Z55jOh5MGGakdFYcTEJBlCpdZQKEGRQAApkEEyemQxQre1QAEoQwHBkCHkA-LHxiUTNcd29njKFmv1ZYxNTMyFECL3tXJwA9BdQvNDjxHCmwCJYDcQA%20gAM4uSUVDJvd4oFSXa4hELhMi6fRGEzmSxcK42XaOPCcW57B5PERuDz6Hx%20QLwZAoGSqSHQxrGMwWKzWehAA)

If you want to you will always operate on one argument function, you can use this code:

```js
type Func1 = (id: string) => void;


type Func2 = (id: string, conf: { extraArg: boolean }) => void;

type AddArgument<
  Fn extends (arg: any) => any,
  Conf
  > =
  Fn extends (id: infer Id) => infer Return
  ? (id: Id, conf: Conf) => Return
  : never;

// type Result = (id: string, conf: {
//     extraArg: boolean;
// }) => void
type Result = AddArgument<Func1, { extraArg: boolean }>
```

> if I would have to "hardcode" every variable preceding the "conf" as I use 2-3 variables in a couple of cases

You can expect second generic argument as a tuple:

```js
type Func1 = (id: string) => void;


type Func2 = (id: string, conf: { extraArg: boolean }) => void;

type AddArgument<
  Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any,
  NextArg extends any[]
  > =
  Fn extends (...arg: [...infer PrevArg]) => infer Return
  ? (...args: [...PrevArg, ...NextArg]) => Return
  : never;

// type Result = (args_0: string, args_1: {
//     extraArg: boolean;
// }) => void
type Result = AddArgument<Func1, [{ extraArg: boolean }, { anotherArg: 42 }]>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried doing it with the above mentioned variadic tuple types. However using this feature still gives me the same problem - even though the variables are not misnamed anymore (which is good), it tampers with their names making them unrecognisable.

Comment: The second example seems more suitable for my case but I wonder if I would have to "hardcode" every variable preceding the "conf" as I use 2-3 variables in a couple of cases

Comment: @Rinta I made an update. If you are confused by the name of argument - you should not worry to much, it does not affect the type itself.

Comment: It seems like variadic tuple types is not the ideal way to go in my case. I want to be able to see the names of the variables I should pass to the function, especially if there's a variable amount of them. While the types you suggested do in fact work, it still isn't enough unfortunately. There may be no way of doing what I am aiming for as of now without just extending the second variant you provided, which is hardcoding the names of the arguments