# Typescript signature for function which increases tuple arity

Tags: typescript, dependent-type

Is it possible to write type-aware declaration for function in Typescript which takes tuple and return new one with appended item, without using function overload?

To be short I need to express function which does the following:

```
[T1, T2, ... Tn] + U => [T1, T2, ... Tn, U]
```

There is an obvious way of doing than with multiple overloads:

```
function append<A, B>(a: [A], b: B): [A, B];
function append<A, B, C>(a: [A, B], c: C): [A, B, C];
function append<A, B, C, D>(a: [A, B, C], d: D): [A, B, C, D];
function append(tuple: any[], b: any): any[] {
  return tuple.concat([b]);
}
```

Is there the way of writing this in form of:

```
function append<T extends any[], U>(t: T, u: U): ??? => ???;
```

Comment: This is doable with caveats, as shown in the question this duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I think this is literally beyond Typescript's comprehension currently.  Consider the function without a declared return type at all:

```
function append<U, T extends any[]>(u: U, ...t: T) {
  return [u, ...t];
}

const a = append(4, 'a', 'b')
```

The constant `a` is obviously of type `[number, string, string]`, but the 3.7.2 compiler thinks it's an `any[]`.

Comment: Yeah, that's great, but the essence is to ensure compiler that `a` is of `[number, string, string]`.

Comment: See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546710/push-type-to-the-end-of-the-tuple) for how one can accomplish tuple appending with caveats.  Also note that your answer is doing *prepending* instead of appending, which can be done with fewer caveats using the `Cons` type in the linked question.